# C, how can a macro register a unittest for execution?

Tags: c, testing, macros, googletest

How can libraries such as GTest use a single macro `G_TEST(...)` to both define the function and register it as a test function? I'm looking for a way to do the same for my C99 project.

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_test_header_that_doesnt_exist.h"

TEST_MACRO(mytest)
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
TEST_MACRO(mytest2)
{
    printf("Hello, world 2\n");
    return 2;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    RUN_TESTS();
    return 0;
}
```

Can't figure out how to register the tests so they are known from `RUN_TESTS()`

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880966/calling-some-functions-before-main-in-c to see how to ensure function in C is executed before main(). Then you can use this trick in your macros. Byteventurer answer properly explains how it is done in C++ but GTest - but you cannot use use this C++ specific trick...

Answer (score 2):

By passing an `-E` option to `g++` you can inspect the code after preprocessing. Example code using the GTest library:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(testcase, mytest) {
    // Code
}

int main() {
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And compiling it with:

```
g++ -E -Igtest_include_path example.cpp -oexample_preprocessed.cpp
```

The TEST macro expanded to:

```
class testcase_mytest_Test : public ::testing::Test {
public:
    testcase_mytest_Test() {}
private:
    virtual void TestBody();
    static ::testing::TestInfo* const test_info_ __attribute__ ((unused));
    testcase_mytest_Test(testcase_mytest_Test const &);
    void operator=(testcase_mytest_Test const &);
};

::testing::TestInfo* const testcase_mytest_Test ::test_info_ = ::testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo( "testcase", "mytest", __null, __null, ::testing::internal::CodeLocation("cpp_test.c", 3), (::testing::internal::GetTestTypeId()), ::testing::Test::SetUpTestCase, ::testing::Test::TearDownTestCase, new ::testing::internal::TestFactoryImpl< testcase_mytest_Test>);

void testcase_mytest_Test::TestBody() {
    // Code
}
```

And RUN_ALL_TESTS() is not a macro:

```
inline int RUN_ALL_TESTS() {
  return ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->Run();
}
```

So it's in fact a complicated chain of preprocessor macros that make up a class out of your test case, and does all sorts of things to link it to the machinery that runs it.

*Obviously you are not going to be able to do it like this in a C99 project, as GTest is a C++ library, and it heavily relies on C++ features to do the job.*

If you wish to understand how it works fully, you should check out the GTest code in its repository: https://github.com/google/googletest