# why can main function call and run the function of other cpp file？

Tags: c++

I create a C++ project `test` that contains three files as follows: 
hello.hpp:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H
int cHelloSay();
#endif
```

hello.cpp:

```
#include "hello.hpp"
#include<iostream>
int sayHello(){
    std::cout << "123";
}
int i=sayHello();
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include "hello.hpp"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

then I compile this project and it outputs:`123`. So I am confused why the line `int i=sayHello();` is executed though `main()` does not call it ?

Comment: in C++ you can call functions when initializing globals. it's called before `main`

Comment: because this line `int i=sayHello();`  - called inside `initterm`

Comment: note that the c tag isn't relevant here. the code cannot work in C because you cannot call functions when initializing globals in C. and it's no C++11 feature either, so plain C++

Comment: Be careful accessing `std::cout` outside of the `main()` scope. That could lead to trouble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [May I initialize a global variable with the result of a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337426/may-i-initialize-a-global-variable-with-the-result-of-a-function-call)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre why is var `i` global var?

Comment: @user0042 [`std::ios_base::Init`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init) makes sures that it works :)

Comment: because it's in global scope.

Comment: @RbMm do not understand initterm

Comment: @Quentin I remember having troubles once. But I'm old, and maybe that was on an embedded system ;-) ...

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre what I mean is different of [it]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337426/may-i-initialize-a-global-variable-with-the-result-of-a-function-call

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre thank you very much. Now I have understood

Comment: @AndrewGong - when you write `int i=sayHello();` compiler create internal function, which call `sayHello();` and put result to `i`. and place pointer to this function in (".CRT$XCA", ".CRT$XCZ") (c++) or (".CRT$XIA", ".CRT$XIZ") (c) section. the `[w]mainCRTStartup` call special function `initterm` (you can found it src code in crt) which walk by this segment and call functions by pointer. read for example [How to execute some code before entering the main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728939/how-to-execute-some-code-before-entering-the-main-routine-in-vc)

Comment: @RbMm thank you very much. I need to learn more

Comment: @AndrewGong - you also can set breakpoint exactly on `int i=sayHello();` line and view from where and how it called.also search for _initterm in crt src

Answer (score 0):

Now I know any variable declared outside a function is a global variable though it is in another *.cpp file. So the line `int i=sayHello();` will be executed before call `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

When after the program is being complied the variables are initialized. As part of this it is calling your `int i=sayHello();` before int main() is called.

Hopes this helps!